# Install 2 apps with same provisioning profile in iOS

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

How to install two apps with same provisioning profile on a device in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcard provisioning profile. Then you just need to Bundle Id in your app, profile remain same though.